# orderBy() in firestore in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore structure like-

`Palettes(collection) --><auto-gen-id1>, <auto-gen-id2> ... -->  { colors: [...], createdAt: TIMESTAMP } (each document)`

I want to fetch all data and order according to timestamp using onSnapshot() listener and store it into state using react hook.
How to use orderBy query in this code below

```
db.collection('palettes').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    if (change.type === "added") {
      setPalette( prevPalette => ([
        { id: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data() },
        ...prevPalette
      ]))
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

You can do:

```
db.collection('palettes').orderBy("createdAt", "desc").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    if (change.type === "added") {
      setPalette( prevPalette => ([
        { id: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data() },
        ...prevPalette
      ]))
    }
  })
})
```

or

```
db.collection('palettes').orderBy("createdAt").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    if (change.type === "added") {
      setPalette( prevPalette => ([
        { id: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data() },
        ...prevPalette
      ]))
    }
  })
})
```

depending on the sorting direction.